# Retina compatibility question: Can I add @2x to my own images for retina compatibility?

Tags: iphone, ios, retina-display

If I append the @2x suffix to my own images, will iOS 4 automatically replace my images with the Retina compatible ones, or does that only apply to Apple defined images? (Icons, for example.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, of course. If you display a `myimage.png` in your app, you may add a retina ready `myimage@2x.png`, so it is shown on retina devices.

See [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW8) for further information.

Comment: Apple updated their URL scheme, the guide is now located here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreens/SupportingHiResScreens.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW8

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> The bundle- and image-loading routines
>   automatically look for image files
>   with the @2x string when the
>   underlying device has a
>   high-resolution screen.

So using for example `[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"]` will automatically look for `MyImage@2x.png` when running on a device with retina display.