# Retina display of images-iPhone 3 to 4

Tags: iphone, image, retina-display

I have developed an application of tile game for iPhone 3.
In which I took an image from my resource and divided it into number of tiles using `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect ( originalImage.CGImage, frame );` function.

It works great on all iPhones but now I want it to work on Retina Displays also.

So as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937204/retina-compatibility-question-can-i-add-2x-to-my-own-images-for-retina-compatib) I have taken anothe image with its size double the current images size and rename it by adding suffix @2x. But the problem is it takes the upper half part of the retina display image only. I think thats because of the frame I have set while using `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`. So What shall be done in respect to make this work.

Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that the @2x image scale is only automatically set up properly for certain initializers of UIImage...  [Try loading your UIImages using code like this from Tasty Pixel.](http://atastypixel.com/blog/uiimage-resolution-independence-and-the-iphone-4s-retina-display/)  The entry at that link talks more about this issue.

Using the `UIImage+TPAdditions` category from the link, you'll implement it like so (after making sure that the images and their @2x counterparts are in your project):

```
NSString *baseImagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *myImagePath = [baseImagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myImage.png"]; // note no need to add @2x.png here
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfResolutionIndependentFile:myImagePath];
```

Then you should be able to use `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(myImage.CGImage, frame);`

Comment: I have tried that too but its not getting the scale==2.0. I have tried it in simulator.

Comment: Also without implementing this It was taking my image with named as @2x as suffix. But now since the above condition dont matches Its not taking my @2x image at all

Comment: I edited my answer -- post a bit of your code if it's not working, and I'll try to help.

Comment: I have done the same thing.. It takes the @2x image.. but still it cuts just he above half portion of the image and omits the below half.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work in an app I did:

```
//this is a method that takes a UIImage and slices it into 16 tiles (GridSize * GridSize)
#define GridSize 4
- (void) sliceImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGSize imageSize = [image size];
    CGSize square = CGSizeMake(imageSize.width/GridSize, imageSize.height/GridSize);

    CGFloat scaleMultiplier = [image scale];

    square.width *= scaleMultiplier;
    square.height *= scaleMultiplier;

    CGFloat scale = ([self frame].size.width/GridSize)/square.width;

    CGImageRef source = [image CGImage];
    if (source != NULL) {
        for (int r = 0; r < GridSize; ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c < GridSize; ++c) {
                CGRect slice = CGRectMake(c*square.width, r*square.height, square.width, square.height);
                CGImageRef sliceImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(source, slice);
                if (sliceImage) {
                    //we have a tile (as a CGImageRef) from the source image
                    //do something with it
                    CFRelease(sliceImage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is using the `-[UIImage scale]` property to figure out how big of a rect you should be slicing.

Comment: so you want to say that if i was taking the slice of 100x100 in iPhone 3 the for retin display i need to take the slice of 200x200? Is it so?

Comment: Tried ur code but it makes the tile bigger hence results in going of tiles out of the screen :(

Comment: @hAPPY iCODER - oh, no.  This is for slicing a UIImage, whether it's myImage.png or myImage@2x.png.

Comment: I have written the code for slicing.. but i need the slice of a 2x image which fits the screen as if it fits in normal images.. Right now slicing of 2x makes the tile much bigger resulting in going it out of screen